# Bit Masking a bit register

Tags: c, avr, bitmask

I am sure this has been asked, but I am having trouble understanding how to bit mask a 8 bit register.

Suppose I have a 8 bit register. The bits are set via `PORTD`. I want to change all the bits except the 2 LSB.

```
PORTD |= 0b111011XX;
```

XX are the 2 LSB I don't want to change.

How do I do this?

Comment: "I want to change all the bits except [...]" -- the 6 upper bits shall all be flipped? That'd require XOR (`^`) instead of OR (`|`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep clear your intent you could separate the masking part from the values you are set, eg:

```
PORTD |= 0b11101100 & ~0b00000011
```

This will get optimized in any case but will clearly explain what you are setting and what you want to keep as it is.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
PORTD |= 0b11101100; // bitwise-OR-ing with 0 retains the original
```

If you want to flip upper 6-bits and want to retain lower 2-bits, you need to do:

```
PORTD ^= 0b11111100; // bitwise-XOR-ing with 1 reverses the bit and with 0 retains
```